# Add (hover) listener for grid cell after grid first attach

Tags: java, gwt, gridview, grid, gxt

I have something like this.

```
Grid<Stock> mygrid = new Grid<Stock>(store, cm)
{
    @Override
    protected void onAfterFirstAttach() 
    {       
        super.onAfterFirstAttach();
        //here do the binding for the cell elements that have myclass
    }
};
```

And for the view of `mygrid` I have this

```
view.setViewConfig(new GridViewConfig<Stock>()
{
    @Override
    public String getRowStyle(Stock model, int rowIndex)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getColStyle(Stock model, ValueProvider<? super Stock, ?> valueProvider, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
    {       
        String style = "";
        if(SOME_CASE)
        {
            style = "myclass"; 
        }

        return style;
    }
});
```

What I want to do is `onAfterFirstAttach` I want to add some listener/handler that during `hover` will do something, let's say for the sake of simplicity, give an `alert`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Can I accomplish what I want without using `JSNI` or a library like `gwtquery`? Is it sure that `onAfterFirstAttach` all the cells that should have the class `myclass` will be available and accessible? If yes how can I attach the listener/handler that I want?

The questions seem a lot, but I believe they are all interconnected.

I'm using GWT 2.6 with GXT 3.1 on top of it.

**Update**

I forgot to mention that a feasible solution would be to add a [listener for the mouse move](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185981-Row-hover-event-for-grid) on the whole grid, and then get each cell and check if it has the required class, but this seems such an overkill. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GTX, but I'm sure you can try mygrid.addMouseOverHandler() - If the Grid doesn't implement HasMouseOverHandler, you can subclass it and implement it yourself :) - Oh, you're trying to set CSS classes when you hover a cell. Since I'm not familiar with GXT Grid, I'm not sure, but I'd add the DOM listener at the cell itself maybe

Comment: Yes but this adds a listener on the grid. If possible I would like to add handlers only for the specified cells in order to avoid the additional overhead. My app consists of a large enough grid and I want to minimize the overhead as much as possible.

Comment: "specified cells" - can you get those at runtime then add the listener there? I'm don't know the Grid from GTX, maybe there is a way to waddle trough it's rows? Sorry for being not so helpful

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking the time. Actually I don't since I'm a newbie on both GXT and GWT.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, maybe there is another way to do it :)

Comment: @alkis - Any other solution will have the same overhead - or even more. Attaching listeners to individual cells is the worst solution performance-wise.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin That's very interesting! Could you please elaborate? Maybe post your thoughts as an answer. It will be a good reference.

Comment: @André I'm trying to emulate the excel functionality of showing the comment of a cell when hovering that particular cell. But we don't have to complicate it. Just think of an alert that displays the value of that cell, that way we can keep it simple for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser fires native events (click, focus, blur, etc.) regardless of whether you need them. These events "bubble up" the DOM tree giving you a chance to "listen" to them at the right level.

In your example you can create 30 listeners at the cell level, waiting for something to happen in "their" cell. This is a heavy (30 objects) and slow (it takes time to build and bind all of them) solution. Alternatively, you can create a single listener at the grid level, which listens to all events  that bubble up from the cells and decides if something needs to be done or an event should be ignored. A single listener is lighter and can be created faster. On the flip side, it needs to examine events, although it's usually a fast and efficient operation (e.g. checking of an event source has a particular class name). Note also that this operation takes time when a browser typically does not have much to do anyway, so examining events only to ignore them does not impact user experience.

In my experience a single listener is almost always a better solution, although modern browsers and computers are so fast that the difference is rarely noticeable.